# How to sort DataTable when working with JSF

Tags: jsf, datatables

When I receive a list of persons in a DataTable, the 'dateOfBirth' entries ( column in dataTable) appear unsorted. The front page has been developed using JSF.

Prior to the creation of the DataTable, I have implemented some code to ensure sorting on the server side. However, my objective is to determine how to achieve this sorting on the front end ( client-side).

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelpersonList" rendered="#{paramListePersonControllerAction.consulterPerson()}">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="display" id="personsList" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th >#{bundlesweb.personDate}</th>
                    <th >#{bundlesweb.personNomContact}</th>
                    <th >#{bundlesweb.personStatut}</th>
                    <th >#{bundlesweb.personAgent}</th>
                    <th >#{bundlesweb.personheure}</th>
                    
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <ui:repeat
                    value="#{listepersonControllerAction.listpersons}"
                    var="person">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="visible-lg visible-md visible-sm ">
                        <h:outputText value="#{person.dateOfBirth}" >
                                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </td>
                        <td>#{person.typeperson}</td>
                        <td>#{person.statutperson.libelle}</td>
                        <td>#{person.agent}</td>
                        <td>#{person.heureperson}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Here is the code java script (i didn't mention the block script in the code above):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});

function initPersonList(){
    const PERSON_LIST= '#personList';
    if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( PERSON_LIST) ) {
        $(PERSON_LIST).DataTable().destroy();
    }       
    
    $(PERSON_LIST).DataTable({
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50],
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        ordering: true,
        order: [[0, 'asc']],
        serverSide: false,
        paging: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { type: 'date', targets: 0 } 
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: I would not reinvent the wheel and simply use the PrimeFaces dataTable. See for example https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml